# KnockoutJs Validation Async isValidating always true

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

At a high level, I am trying to prevent form submission before async validation is complete and also ensure all is valid before submitting the form...

View Model Excerpt:

```
 ko.validation.rules['projectNameValidator'] = {
        async: true,
        validator: function (val, otherVal, callback) {
            if (self.ProjectId && self.ProjectId() > 0 && val === self.OriginalProjectName())
                return true;

            $.post("/ValidationBuild/IsProjectNameAvailable?name=" + val, function (data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    };

ko.validation.registerExtenders();

  self.Name.extend({
        required: { message: 'Please Provide a project name' },
        projectNameValidator: { message: 'You have already used this project name, please use a unique project name' }
    });

 self.isValidating = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Name.isValidating();
    });

    self.errors = ko.validation.group(self);

 self.formSubmit = saveData;

    return self;

  function saveData(data, event) {

        if (self.isValidating()) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                saveData(data, event);
            }, 50);
            return false;
        }

       // ko.validation check if valid
        if (self.errors().length > 0) {
            self.errors.showAllMessages(true);
            return;
        }
```

My problem is that `self.isValidating` is always true, I got this code from the answer to this StackOverflow question here: [Knockout Validation async validators: Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721951/knockout-validation-async-validators-is-this-a-bug-or-am-i-doing-something-wron)

The only difference is that my saveData function is not part of the `self` or `this` viewModel like the answer example is but I don't think that matters.

Why is `isValidating` always true?

Comment: Have you called `ko.validation.init`?

Comment: How is `self.Name` defined?

Comment: self.Name is just a ko.observable, I am using ko.mapping.fromJS to "auto" create observables from the json model from the server

Comment: I do not call ko.validation.init, do I need do, my validation does work and fires off validation errors